# Is it possible to have a SPA containing multiple other SPAs with Durandal?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, single-page-application, durandal

Please see the article: ASP.NET MVC 4 pluggable application modules (http://geekswithblogs.net/cokobware/archive/2013/01/15/asp.net-mvc-4-pluggable-application-modules.aspx).

We’re trying to design a large SPA system where a shell or container SPA would contain multiple other SPAs.  Referencing the article, each of the separate areas – Marketing, Sales, Billing, Inventory, Warehouse – would be their own self-contained SPA that are contained within the main, shell application.  We’re thinking right now that we’d like each area to be an MVC app to serve up the SPA but then use

Anyway, can Durandal be used in such a situation?  If so, how?

Would Durandal have to be added to and used in each individual area?

Or are we way overthinking this?  Should we just have one MVC app and use folders under Durandal’s App folder to separate out our areas (e.g., /App/viewmodels/app1, /App/viewmodels/app2, /App/views/app1, /App/views/app2, etc.)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After prototyping a solution for a while, we weren't happy with the results of using MVC areas for a Durandal-based SPA.  There may be a good way to do it, but we decided to go with a pure client-side solution, using Durandal 2 (much better routing than 1.2.0 with Sammy).
Thanks.